# react native create text input using looping data

Tags: react-native

How to render text input dynamically by looping data on react native.
Like this (example)

```
foreach (data as d) {....

return '<input type="hidden" id="name'+d.id+'" value="'+d.name+'" />
<input id="price'+d.id+'" value="+d.price+" onchange="send('+d.id+')"/>'; 

....}

function send(id) {
   var name = $('#name'+id).val();
   var price = $('#price'+id).val();

   ....
}
```

[Example screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fuY7.jpg)

By sample screen above, i want when each spinner change calling a function like jquery sample above

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you (use you on parameter names)

```
render(){

        var payments = [];

        for(let i = 0; i < noGuest; i++){

            payments.push(
                <View key = {i}>
                    <View>
                        <TextInput />
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <TextInput />
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <TextInput />
                    </View>
                </View>
            )
        }

        return (
            <View>
                <View>
                    <View><Text>No</Text></View>
                    <View><Text>Name</Text></View>
                    <View><Text>Preference</Text></View>
                </View>

                { payments }
            </View>
        )
    }
```

**Alternatively**

```
render() {
var myloop = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  myloop.push(
    <View key={i}>
    <Text>{i}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

 return (

        <View >
          <Text >Welcome to React Native!</Text>
           {myloop}
        </View>


    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How about to calling function when onchangetext, in function send all data on text input each row

Comment: I understand your question now, you have to use Flat list for such functionality to perform on your screen. when you change a spinner flatlsit automatically re-render and update your state (your onchage function will call in flat list) here is the example,ful for you maybe it helps https://hackernoon.com/how-to-highlight-and-multi-select-items-in-a-flatlist-component-react-native-1ca416dec4bc

Comment: if you don't understand then share your code I will try to fix it